# Error on app compilation using new DJI-UXSDK-iOS 4.7, FFmpeg library not found

Tags: dji-sdk

I just uploaded the DJI-UXSDK-iOS to the newest version (4.7) on my project and I got a compilation error:

`dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FFmpeg.framework/FFmpeg
  Referenced from: /Users/nachocarnicero/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6107CAFD-8BA7-44D6-A059-A971A22BF695/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/44688981-49A3-4F6F-91E2-15E5381BBBB8/perceptionios.app/Frameworks/DJIUXSDK.framework/DJIUXSDK
  Reason: image not found`

So basically it is not finding the FFmpeg library, I believe this has to do with the fact that now the video feedback is included as a widget according to the release notes of the DJI Mobile SDK 4.7:

> Replaced VideoPreviewer with DJIWidget for hardware encoding support

Therefore previously the FFmpeg library was included in the VideoPreviewer framework, but now I guess it has to be included in some other way, has anyone managed to successfully compile projects with this new versions?

Thanks,

Nacho

Answer (score 8):

As stated by Lisa the problem is that I hadn't included the DJIWidget file. But since the inclusion is not straightforward, and since the docs haven't been updated yet I'll post here the steps to successfully compile an iOS app when uploading to DJI Mobile SDK 4.7 :

- Open your project in Xcode and remove the `VideoPreviewer` folder from the `Frameworks` folder
- Clone the `Mobile-UXSDK-iOS` repo. `git clone https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-UXSDK-iOS`
- Copy the folder `Mobile-UXSDK-iOS/Sample Code/DJIWidget` to the root folder where your `*.xcworkspace` is. Be sure to include all the content of the folder:

[image: Folder content]

- Then drag and drop the `DJIWIdget.xcodeproj` and `FFmpeg.framework` to the `Framework` folder of your Xcode project as in this screenshot:

  [image: tree structure]
- Go to your project settings, under the general tab navigate to `Embedded Binaries` and add **only** the `FFmpeg` framework, as in the screenshot below [image: embedded binaries]
- Then wherever you were importing in your code `<VideoPreviewer/VideoPreviewer.h>` you should replace it by `<DJIWidget/DJIWidget.h>`
- Finally in your code you have to replace all the calls to the `VideoPreviewer` component with the renamed component `DJIVideoPreviewer`. So for example `[[VideoPreviewer instance] start];` now should be `[[DJIVideoPreviewer instance] start]`;

And that's it, after that your app should compile and you should have the video feedback from the drone.

Comment: Works great, thanks! Although, I think there's a typo in the last point (needing to replace called to `VideoPreviewer` with `DJIVideoPreviewer`, not the other way around).

Comment: Thanks @ColinBasnett I just edited the answer, it's true that it could be confusing

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you missed bringing in the [DJIWidget file](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-UXSDK-iOS/tree/master/Sample%20Code/DJIWidget) - try integrating that, which should take care of your crash. If you need examples of how to do the integration see our [Sample Code](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-UXSDK-iOS/tree/master/Sample%20Code). Also, you must then remove the ios-videopreviewer project if you were using it previously.​  We have just updated our Release Notes with this tip.

Answer (score 0):

Nacho's answer got me most of the way there but I also need to add the DJIWidget framework to the Embedded Binaries section where the FFMPEG framework was added. After dragging the DJIWidget project into your framework folder it shows up after pressing the "+" at the bottom of this section:

[image]

Also the the DJIWidget project has been moved to it's own separate URL : https://github.com/dji-sdk/DJIWidget

Answer (score 0):

Include "${PODS_ROOT}/DJIWidget/FFmpeg" to the path list under the Framework search paths in the Build settings menu of your project. You'll need to add it to both debug and release.